# How to create this common header layout using CSS Flexbox? (The Odin Project exercise)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to solve a problem from the Odin Project CSS exercises repository, specifically [03-flex-header-2](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/css-exercises/tree/main/flex/03-flex-header-2).

After looking at the provided [solution](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/css-exercises/tree/main/flex/03-flex-header-2/solution) and adding those lines of code into my own code, my result still does not look like the [desired outcome](https://github.com/TheOdinProject/css-exercises/blob/main/flex/03-flex-header-2/desired-outcome.png). The logo and links should be all the way on the left side of the header, while the notification button and purple circle are supposed to be all the way on the right. I don't understand why my code doesn't produce the same result since I simply typed their solution code into my own.

Here is my own code (I have just added in the lines provided in their solution):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Besley:ital,wght@0,400;1,900&display=swap');
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Besley, serif;
}

.header {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  // lines below added from the solution code
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 8px;
}

// lines below added from the solution code
.left,
.right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
}

.profile-image {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

.logo {
  color: rebeccapurple;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: italic;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 24px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rebeccapurple;
  padding: 8px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  // lines below added from the solution code
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  gap: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flex Header 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="left-side">
      <div class="logo">
        LOGO
      </div>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="google.com">link-one</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.com">link-two</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.com">link-three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
      <button class="notifications">
          1 new notification
        </button>
      <div class="profile-image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is how it looks in my browser:

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your class names in the HTML. They do not match with the selectors in the css (`right-side`instead of `right`etc.) ;)

Comment: Such a stupid mistake! Thank you for your help!

Comment: we all did it. and I still do, more frequently that I'd be comfortable to admit :-D